# Isoperimetric inequality for closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, isoperimetric-problems

A well known isoperimetric inequality for closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be generalized to closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, see: https://mathoverflow.net/a/321505/121665.

I have two questions:

> **Question 1.** Is it possible to prove a reasonable isoperimetric inquality for closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$?
>
> **Questions 2.** Can an inequality from https://mathoverflow.net/a/321505/121665 be generalized to smooth
> mappings of $\mathbb{S}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n>k+1$?

Has anyone seen any related results?

There is a general isoperimetric inequality for currents (Theorem 6.1 in [1]) that has been generalized in many ways, but I am looking for a more elementary statements, more in the spirit of  https://mathoverflow.net/a/321505/121665.

[1] *Federer, H.; Fleming, W. H.*, [**Normal and integral currents**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970227), Ann. Math. (2) 72, 458-520 (1960). [ZBL0187.31301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0187.31301).

Answer (score 2):

I found one related isoperimetric inequality due to 
Schoenberg [1].

We say that a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is *convex* provided it never crosses a hyperplane more than $2n$ times.

> **Theorem.** Let $C$ be a closed convex curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ of length $L$. Let $K$ be the convex hull of $C$.
>   Then $$ L^{2n}\geq (2\pi n)^n n! (2n)! |K|. $$

Moreover Schoenberg determined all cases of equality.

The paper of Schoenberg has 12 citations in MathSciNet and some of these papers contain generalizations of Schoenberg's result. In particular Tilli [1] (Corollary 1.3) proved

> **Theorem.** Assume $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set.  Let $K$ be the convex hull of $C$. Then $$ \mathcal{H}^1(C)^n\geq (n!)^2|K|,
> $$ where $\mathcal{H}^1$ stands for the Hausdorff measure.

Clearly the result applies to curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of finite length.

See also: [Maximizing an integral w.r.t. a measure on the unit sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/322846/121665).

**[1] Schoenberg, I. J.,**
[An isoperimetric inequality for closed curves convex in even-dimensional Euclidean spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485892064)
.
*Acta Math.* 91, (1954). 143-164. 
[(MathSciNet review)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=156700&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=127&mx-pid=65944%0A).

**[2] Tilli, P.,**
[Isoperimetric inequalities for convex hulls and related questions.](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2010-362-09/S0002-9947-10-04734-3/home.html) .
*Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* 362 (2010),  4497-4509. 
[(MathSciNet review)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=610927&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=19&mx-pid=2645038).

Comment: I found Tilli's paper extremely interesting, thanks for pointing it out! Accidentally do you know if the Problem 1.3 (mentioned there in the paper) has a solution now? (I have posted the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322846/maximizing-an-integral-w-r-t-a-measure-on-the-unit-sphere) in a separate topic). Thanks again for the interesting reference!

Comment: @Romeo I am happy to see that my miserable activity on Mathoverflow sometimes makes some sense.

Comment: Don't even say it as a joke :-)! I do find your contributions really interesting and I thank you for your activity on MO. (Btw thanks also for the answer concerning estimates of incremental quotients in Sobolev spaces: I need some time to digest it :-)). Looking forward to reading you again soon ;-)